# avoid overwriting the same text file in batch script for loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm really new at writing batch script, but I'm trying to find all the occurrences of a string in multiple files and write these strings to a txt file by using a for loop. Here's what I have:

```
for %%i in (a.log b.log c.log) do 
(
   find /I "error" %%i > check.txt
)
```

But somehow, `check.txt only contains the strings from c.log and not from the previous two, probably overwrote`.

Is there a way to avoid overwriting?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` creates a file anew.

`>>` appends to an existing file or creates it if it doesn't already exist.